# Algorithm for finding if sum of sub array elements can make a desired sum

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement an algorithm which will tell if the the desired sum can be make out from the given array elements.

I have came up with this program

```
def check_payment(arr, requested_money):
arr.sort()
arr.reverse()
sum = 0
for item in arr:
    sum += item 
    if sum == requested_money:
        return True
    elif sum > requested_money:
        sum -= item

return False
```

I dont know where it is getting wrong. Some test cases are failing. Can you please provide me a scenario where this will fail.

Comment: *I dont know where it is getting wrong* - everywhere, actually. It is backtracking only if the last element checked is overflowing, but doesn't care about the previous elements. This type of problems are naturally solved using recursion.

Comment: Possible approach: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20151221002246/http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Comment: As far as I understand from your problem definition, this is an NP-Complete problem known as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem. So, there is not a polynomial time (i.e. short time) algorithm for this problem if your data set is large. What is the size of your data?

Comment: Data set is not large. Array size is less than 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario - Where your code fails

Run your code for this array:-

```
[10,16,25] - original array say arr
arr.sort() - [10,16,25]
arr.reverse() - [25,16,10]
```

Now apply that for loop and search for `requested_money 26`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please see the last line of his question  - I dont know where it is getting wrong. Some test cases are failing. Can you please provide me a scenario where this will fail.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it and removed my comment, sorry

Comment: No problem Eugene

Comment: Thanks a lot for the case. This will help.

Comment: @DiamondMohanty Glad to help you